# Finding Coordinates of a curve passing through a point

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a curve whose values of y ranges from -500 to -1500 and x 0 to 300 and I have a line where y = -1250. I need to find the coordinates of all values in the curve intersecting the line. How do i do that?

This question might sound stupid. And I know how to find the same for one single intersection. But what should I do when there are many intersections?

New to programming and linear functions. any suggestions, or links would be appreciated. thank u

Comment: you want to find the roots of the polynomial http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac03/fac03.html

Comment: Can you give an example of such a curve?

Comment: What kind of curve is it? There is a handy function for polynomials: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html

Comment: By "curve" do you mean a mathematical equation (or analytic solution of some sort) or do you mean a set of observed data points that you want to interpolate between?  The solution will depend on whether you're dealing with a mathematical function or discrete points.